# In c whats the difference between (a+b) and (a + b)?

Tags: c, output

```
#define ADD1(a,b)(a+b)
#define ADD2(a,b)(a + b)

x=5,y=2
z1=ADD1(x.++y);
printf("%d %d %d",x,y,z1);
x=5,y=2
z2=ADD2(x,++y);
printf("%d %d %d",x,y,z2);
```

The answer is
x=6,y=2,z1=7
x=5.y=3,z=8

`I thought the output in both is x=5,y=3,z1/z2=8
why theres a difference between them?```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that actually compiles, without the typos?

Comment: Spaces are slightly more readable, but both are missing parens

Comment: I don't like editing code in questions, but it looks like that `z1=ADD1(x.++y);` should be `z1=ADD1(x,++y);` (dot for comma). If so, please edit accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `ADD1` results in `x+++y`. That is evaluated as `x++ + y`, and not  `x + ++y` as you had expected. Note that, in that computation, `x++` does not have any effect on the result, because `x` is incremented after the addition.

See a demonstration here: https://onlinegdb.com/EvqOw8s87

You should use parentheses in your definitions, to avoid such ambiguities:

```
#define ADD1(a,b)((a)+(b))
#define ADD2(a,b)((a) + (b))
```

This makes them behave the same